# CodeIgniter: PHP Error: Invalid arg in foreach() in Table.php : line 198

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

I have done a pretty thorough search about this error, and although I find alot of general answers about 'ensuring that you're passing an array or SQL query', I think I may need more specific help per the CodeIgniter Libraries.

I have a view that is just supposed to create a query (or array) and generate a table.

(Eventually, the query will happen from a model and the table generation will be a function in my controller so I can reuse it in other views, but I'm starting out with just the basic echo to screen)

The view is set up as such:

```
<div class="span4 well well-small">
            <h4>Requests:</h4>
            <?php
                $this->table->set_heading('ID', 'Request', 'User', 'Date');

                $query = array('id'=>'123', 'request'=>'FARTS', 'user'=>'Steve', 'date'=>'Today'); //$this->db->select('user_id', 'password', 'user_name', 'company_id')->from('users');
                echo $this->table->generate($query);
            ?>
            <h4>In this div:</h4>
            <p>we will display some information about recent requests. It will show a small table with Request ID, Request Name, and Date Requested headers.</p>
</div>
```

This prints a box with 4 PHP error boxes saying :

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: libraries/Table.php

Line Number: 198

When I check line 198 in the Table.php library, it requires an array (associative or not), or a query from a DB. I have attempted to pass a non-associative array, an associative array, and a db query, all of which produce this same error.

And, so you don't have to go leafing through CI, here is the function throwing the error:

```
function _prep_args($args)
{
    // If there is no $args[0], skip this and treat as an associative array
    // This can happen if there is only a single key, for example this is passed to table->generate
    // array(array('foo'=>'bar'))
    if (isset($args[0]) AND (count($args) == 1 && is_array($args[0])))
    {
        // args sent as indexed array
        if ( ! isset($args[0]['data']))
        {
            foreach ($args[0] as $key => $val)
            {
                if (is_array($val) && isset($val['data']))
                {
                    $args[$key] = $val;
                }
                else
                {
                    $args[$key] = array('data' => $val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($args as $key => $val)
        {
            if ( ! is_array($val))
            {
                $args[$key] = array('data' => $val);
            }
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your $query variable to be like this:

```
$query = array(array('id'=>'123', 'request'=>'FARTS', 'user'=>'Steve', 'date'=>'Today'));
```

That method is expecting an array of arrays, even if there is no specific key=>value pair.

```
$query = array(array('123','FARTS','Steve', 'Today'));
```

In essence, that is also what your database query should be returning when you use CI's database library.

Personally, unless you are going to use data straight from the db query, I would use:

```
$this->table->add_row('123','FARTS','Steve', 'Today');
-OR-
$this->table->add_row(array('ID'=>'hello','class'=>'Today','data'=>'Displayed Text'));
```

As far as you database query getting the same error, I would triple check what kind of output you're actually recieving from said query.

Hope this helps

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I see it now. I wasn't passing the array of arrays through, just an array. The $this->table->addrow(); is my next step. I was just using the dummy array for simplicity. I appreciate it.